# ASP.NET MVC - Why is ModelState.IsValid returning true after I set ModelMetadata.IsRequired programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I have got an extension method which I call from within my EditorTemplate (for a string) which sets the Label and the Required metadata on the on the control. (I cannot annotate my models so this is why I am doing this).

```
 public static void SetMetadata(this ViewUserControl control)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)control.ViewData["labeltext"]))
            control.ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName = (string)control.ViewData["labeltext"];

        if (control.ViewData["required"] != null)
            control.ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired = (bool)control.ViewData["required"];
    }
```

Has anyone got any ideas why ModelState.IsValid would not be picking up on the fields I have set to *Required = true*?

Comment: why can't you annotate your viewmodels?

Comment: @chad-ruppert The models are business entities coming from a webservice, I only have access to the proxy classes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are modifying the `ModelMetadata` on your `get` request of the page.  This information is not persisted when you `post` to your action (as there is no `ViewState`esque mechanism in MVC).

Is the class you attempting to validate marked as `partial`? If so, you can use the cool `MetadataType` attribute to decorate the class with validation attributes:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(JobOpening_Validation))]
public partial class JobOpening
{
     //JobOpening is generated by LinqToSql but I want to validate the Title Property
}

internal class JobOpening_Validation
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 150 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Using this "throwaway" (`JobOpening_Validation`) class we create the same properties we want validated on the "target" (`JobOpening`) class. Any decorating of the attributes on the "throwaway" class will be copied to "target" class.

If this doesn't work for you, you can create a `FilterAttribute` and override the `OnActionExecuting` method and perform the validation of your model in there.  You will also be able to update the modelstate accordingly.

Comment: @nathan-anderson Thanks for the feedback. This does sound like a reasonable approach but not quite what I was after. I don't really want to markup the view model as it is a proxy class coming from a webservice. Maybe MVC Extensions - using configuration to modify the metadata will be the way to go.

Comment: Would there be any way I can access the metadata that I am setting in the `EditorTemplate` through to `ActionMethod` on Post?

Comment: Not without posting the metadata itself and performing some form of interpretation not unlike the `FilterAttribute` option I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with using MvcExtensions - and failing because is was just too difficult to shoehorn it into my project. I ended finding a brilliant little project called [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com)

It's easy to use and integrates easily with MVC.